# Don't understand this NameError from auto email when HTML is changed error

Tags: python

I am making a script that will email you every time the HTML is changed on a website. I am getting a `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined` But I do have pip installed.

Just some interesting info: I am making this for a middle school science fair project `:P` I know I'm being stupid because this is such a basic script.

```
while True:
    url = "https://skyward.smsd.org/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplus/sfcalendar002.w"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)'
                             ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                             ' Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    if str(soup).find("skyward") == -1:
        time.sleep(60)
        continue
    else:
        msg = 'Subject: This is the script talking, check Skyward'

        #Possibilty to make this tell you exactly what is changed
        #A text feature that goes out daily for missing assignments
        fromaddr = '3078774@smsd.org'
        toaddrs  = ['3078774@smsd.org']
        print('From: ' + fromaddr)
        print('To: ' + str(toaddrs))
        print('Message: ' + msg)
        break
```

Comment: Even when you have pip installed you need to `import` the libraries in code.

Comment: Add an `import requests` line at the top.